# I am unable to accept Android SDK licenses when installing Android SDK for flutter through command line

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

I tried everything mention on different questions on github and stackoverflow but failed.
I also tried uninstalling  and re-installing sdk 2 times.

When i run `sdkmanager --licenses` it shows `unknown command : --licenses`

When I run `flutter doctor -v` ,it shows one issue found `SDK licenses not accepted`

What I Have:

JDK 8
Platform-tools 30.0.1
Build-tools 28.0.3
SDK Tool 25.2.5[Obsolete](I could not prevent it from downloading as it is required for the Andorid emulator)
SDK Platform API 28
Emulator: Android 9(API 28) Intel x86 Atom System Image

Answer (score 2):

1) Open your terminal

2) Type `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

3) If you don't see y/n option , continue hitting `enter key` to read through the license

4) When you get option to press `Y/N` , press `Y` to accept every license.

Comment: Terminal doesn't give me chance to press enter as it halts the process saying Unknown Command --licenses. Please help I am not able to run android app. Please check if there is any problem with my versions of sdk tools as mentioned above in question.

Comment: I resolved this isssue by unistalling my emulator and SDK Tool 25.2.5 and accepted all licenses but now I have another problem which is  "Android SDK file not found: adb". This pops up when i run flutter doctor -v

Comment: crosscheck if you have adb file present inside ˜/Android/sdk/platform-tools folder ? if not try installing adb tools or reinstall android studio. after that you should be able to run the adb command from terminal. e.g try running 'adb devices' to check the connected android devices/emulators

Comment: It worked for me thanks. I found that adb.exe was missing so reinstalled sdk and fixed it

Comment: Glad you found the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You should run `flutter clean` in terminal. Then restart your IDE. It will resolve the issues

Answer (score 0):

To accept licences run this `flutter doctor --android-licenses` then `y`  to accept

Comment: It doesn't work. Terminal shows can recognise command and shows bunch of possible command which doesn't include --licenses. Please check is there any problem in version of my sdk tools as mentioned in the question.

Comment: is flutter exported to path?

Comment: I resolved this isssue by unistalling my emulator and SDK Tool 25.2.5 and accepted all licenses but now I have another problem which is  "Android SDK file not found: adb". This pops up when i run flutter doctor -v

Comment: quite weird, do you by any chance have two sdks  cause if you uninstall the sdk you shouldnt be able to accept licences